# How to show count for messages which are hidden below the scroll using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollview

I need to show counter for loaded but scroll down messages in conversation screen. Suppose there are 15 messages in total but showing only 6 on browser right now. It means 9 messages are hidden in below so counter should display 9. But when I scroll up or down counter should change the value accordingly visible and hidden messages.

```
        function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
         var $elem = $(elem);
        var $window = $(window);

        var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
            var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

            var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
            var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >=        docViewTop));
        }
            var message = $('#messages');
            $(window).scroll(function() {
        if (isScrolledIntoView('#hiddenElem')) {
      message.text("Visible");
        } else {
      message.text("Invisible");
    }
  });
```

Check code in [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeoZoe/duj8xz0t/1). Also JavaScript code written for show hidden or visible element.

Comment: if($('.msg').is(":visible")){
alert($('.msg').length)
} This will show all the visible one, can we specify the one parent div and height for it?

Comment: can you update in my fiddle please?

Comment: sorry it's showing me 36 means total messages. I need to show count for only not visible messages which are below the screen

Comment: http://opensource.teamdf.com/visible/examples/demo-basic.html refer this

Comment: Thank you Hema for your help. Learned new something today.

Comment: Thanks Leo,I'm also new to this concept and Learned it.Kudos to your question :)

Comment: When posting code, please do not just post a Fiddle link, and please do not post that link as a comment in order to avoid the editor restrictions. That ultimately needs to be repaired, and so it causes an editor more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare the position of each messages with the scrolled value.
So you need to loop throught them.

Here is something working:

```
var messages=$(".msg");

$(window).scroll(function(){
  var counter=0;
  for(i=0;i<messages.length;i++){
    if( messages.eq(i).offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() ){
      counter++;
    }
  }
  // Display result.
  $("#messages").html(counter);
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/9rxzntms/)

Comment: One confusion how counter is decremented here?

Comment: It is not. On each `scroll` event, the counter is resetted to zero and the loop counts again.